# Why do I get different solutions when integrating both sides of an identity?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve an integral, and I get different solutions, but I basically integrate the same funtion.

My problem is based on the following identity, of which I am confident it is correct:
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{8} \ \left(x-\sqrt{8}\right)} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{8} \ x -16}$$

Now, when I integrate the left side, I get:
$$\int \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{8} \ \left(x-\sqrt{8}\right)} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \ln\left(x-\sqrt{8}\right) + C$$

And when I integrate the right side, I get:
$$ \int \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{8} \ x -16} \mathrm{d}x =  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \ln\left(\sqrt{32} \ x - 16\right) + C$$

Which is a different solution. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a remark: when you integrate something like $\frac{1}{x}$ you get $\ln |x|$ and not $\ln(x)$.

Comment: the integration is not totally correct for $x\in\Bbb R$. If $x\in\Bbb R$ then $\int\frac1xdx=\ln|x|+C$. Besides that your solutions are both correct.

Comment: When integrating functions of a complex variable, the formula $\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln(|x|)+C$ is **wrong** but $\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln(x)+C$ is **right**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\ln(\sqrt{32} x - 16) = \ln\left(\sqrt{32} (x - \sqrt{8})\right) = \ln(\sqrt{32}) + \ln(x - \sqrt{8}).
$$
Hence, the constant term $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}\ln(\sqrt{32})$ can be absorbed in the integration constant.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong. What you got is that $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \ln\left(x-\sqrt{8}\right)$ is *a* primitive of your function, whereas $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \ln\left(\sqrt{32} \ x - 16\right)$ is *another* primitive. Since they differ by a constant, there is no problem.